# Java make a separate annotation that combines a others

Tags: java, annotations, playframework-2.0, jackson

Working with Play Framework 2.2, making a RESTfull API.

In a model I'm using, I wanted to output(Json with Jackson) only the Id of a related object, not the entire object. I found how to do that, as follows:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
@JsonIgnore
public Object myObject;
```

The Json output will contain a JsonNode "myObjectId: 1". For instance.

The IdentityInfo and IdentityReference take care of this.

The problem is, wherever I want this, I have to paste down these 3 lines, along with any other annotations that need to be present for a certain field. This get grow too large and I'm trying to create just 1 custom annotation that does all these things together.

Is this possible, and how? A link where I can read about it or an example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve your problem you have to create an annotation annotated with [JacksonAnnotationInside](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonAnnotationsInside.java) and annotations you want it to 'include'.

The Javadoc of that annotation says that it is:

> Meta-annotation (annotations used on other annotations) used for
>   indicating that instead of using target annotation (annotation
>   annotated with this annotation), Jackson should use meta-annotations
>   it has. **This can be useful in creating "combo-annotations" by having a
>   container annotation, which needs to be annotated with this annotation
>   as well as all annotations it 'contains'.**

For example for your case you'd have something like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JacksonAnnotationsInside // this is important
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {    
}
```

Then you can use it normally as you would Jackson annotations

```
@MyCustomAnnotation
public Object myObject;
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass values of params?
for e.g.

```@MyCustomAnnotation(nestedValue = value)
public Object myObject;```


```@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = nestedValue)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {    
}```

Comment: @Shubham it's possible if you are using **Spring framework** >= 4.2. There is an specific annotatino - `@AliasFor`. [See here for details](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aliasfor-annotation)