# How to combine multiple annotations to single one?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have two annotations from a framework. Often I use those two annotations both on the same field. Thus I'm trying to create a "combined" annotation that contains that both two.

But I don't know if it is possible at all:

**The existing annotations** (that I have no control of):

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApiParam {
    String name() default "";
}

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApiModelProperty {
    String name() default "";
}
```

**My Custom annotation** that I'm trying to create:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
@ApiParam
@ApiModelProperty
public @interface SwaggerParam {
     String name() default "";
}
```

**Result:** the annotations are *not applicable to annotation type*.

**Question:** Is there any chance?

Comment: I think below link can help you solving the problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562005/java-make-a-separate-annotation-that-combines-a-others)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you can't do this since it is not possible to extend annotations.

[Is there something like Annotation Inheritance in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761513/is-there-something-like-annotation-inheritance-in-java)

When I first answered this I was initially confused by the Spring framework approach to this shortcoming whereby they use meta level annotations (such as @Component as a meta annotation for @Controller/@Configuration etc.) as a sort of workaround.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config

Answer (score 2):

Composing annotations like you did can only be done if your framework supports scanning for meta-annotations. Thus the framework not only has to scan for direct annotations but also for an annotation's meta-annotations recursively.

Multiple frameworks support this, some of which are:

- junit: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-meta-annotations
- Spring: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/meta-annotation.html
- Swagger: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53266819/1235217