# How to make an annotaion that calls other annotations

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, lombok, java-annotations

I usually use specific lombok and spring annotations in every class that I open in work.

Is there a way that I can create my custom annotation that will call the annotations that I need?

This is my class for exmple:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class SomeName{}
```

And I want it to be:

```
@SomeAnnotationName
public class SomeName{}
```

Comment: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175378/how-to-combine-multiple-annotations-to-single-one?rq=1), also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761513/is-there-something-like-annotation-inheritance-in-java) may be you can find useful information

Comment: Seems that it cannot do it now https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lombok` doesn't support this, but it have [feature request](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/557) for it.